# R shiny: selectInput() doesn't reflect the variable selection when multiple=TRUE

Tags: file, variables, upload, shiny, interactive

I've written a small shiny app to test the variable selection function for user uploaded data. Here is my code:

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("CSV Data explorer"),
  sidebarPanel(

    fileInput('datafile', 'Choose CSV file',
          accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain')),

    htmlOutput("varselect", inline=TRUE),

    selectInput("vars", "Select a variable:",choices=htmlOutput("varselect")),

    br()  
  ),

  mainPanel(

    dataTableOutput("table")

  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(session,input, output) {

  Dataset <- reactive({
  infile <- input$datafile
  if (is.null(infile)) {

    return(NULL)
  }
  read.csv(infile$datapath)
  })

  observe({
  output$varselect <- renderUI({

    if (identical(Dataset(), '') || identical(Dataset(),data.frame())) return(NULL)

      updateSelectInput(session, inputId="vars", label="Variables to use:",
                    choices=names(Dataset()), selected=names(Dataset()))

    })
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({

  if (is.null(input$vars) || length(input$vars)==0) return(NULL)

  return(Dataset()[,input$vars,drop=FALSE])
  })

})
```

if you go ahead and test it on any of your csv files, you will see 2 problems:
1. there is a mess showing all the variable names above the selectInput() box and this is caused by the code:

htmlOutput("varselect", inline=TRUE)

but if I delete this line of code my selectInput is going to disappear.

2. the selectInput only allows for single variable selection, if I change to

selectInput("vars", "Select a variable:",choices=htmlOutput("varselect"), multiple=TRUE),

and try to click on multiple choices, it is not going to be reflected in the table in the main panel.

I've been struggling with this problem for some time. Could someone help out please! Millions of thanks in advance!

Regards,
mindy

Comment: So to clarify, are you just trying to have the user select which variables (i.e. column names) to display in the datatable?  What is your goal?

Comment: Hi cdeterman, thanks for your response. Yes I try to allow user to select multiple variables to display in the table (as well as for further analysis such as multivariate regression, which is not yet reflected in the above codes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have made yours overly complicated.  Briefly, you only really need a `uiOutput` in place of your `htmlOutput` and `selectInput` statements in your ui.R.  There also doesn't appear to be any need for the `updateSelectInput` or `observe` functions.  You can simplify your code to the following and the multiple select appears to work appropriately:

ui.R

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("CSV Data explorer"),
  sidebarPanel(

    fileInput('datafile', 'Choose CSV file',
              accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain')),

    uiOutput("varselect"),
    br()  
  ),

  mainPanel(

    dataTableOutput("table")

  )
))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(session,input, output) {

  Dataset <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {

      return(NULL)
    }
    read.csv(infile$datapath)
  })

  output$varselect <- renderUI({

    if (identical(Dataset(), '') || identical(Dataset(),data.frame())) return(NULL)

    cols <- names(Dataset())
    selectInput("vars", "Select a variable:",choices=cols, selected=cols, multiple=T)  

  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({

    if (is.null(input$vars) || length(input$vars)==0) return(NULL)

    return(head(Dataset()[,input$vars,drop=FALSE]))
  })

})
```

Comment: Hi cdeterman - thanks but still not working on my side? I can make multiple choices of variables but the table in the main panel still displays all variables..Ideally I would like to see when I select only a subset of variables, only the subset of the data will be displayed and used in analysis.

Comment: The code currently sets all variables as selected (to mimic your initial code).  Can you 'delete' variables from being selected?  You could also remove the 'selected' part from `selectInput` if you want to start from no variables.

Comment: Hi cdeterman, I tried the deleting variables as well still the table doesn't reflect the subset selection. I changed the above code to include 0 variables at the beginning but still no luck. Maybe it's dependent of the data set? Here is the test data set I've used: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25945599/scores.csv

Comment: @cloudy, your dataset works fine for me.  Hm... what version of shiny are you using?  Also, please make sure you have the exact code I provided above.

Comment: hi cdeterman, there must be something that I'm missing. I ran the exact app as above but the subset selection doesn't seem to work? https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wh56rvbks00rsp/readcsv.jpg?dl=0 here is a screenshot where you see I've selected only 2 variables but the main panel table displays the whole data set.

Comment: @cloudy, I see now, you shouldn't click on the variable names.  Click just after the 'term3' and press 'backspace' to remove variables.  You can move between any variable and 'delete' the selection.  If the variable is no longer 'selected' and you click in the box you will get a dropdown of the remaining variables.